# usage of heuristic function in alpha beta pruning

Tags: artificial-intelligence, minimax, heuristics, alpha-beta-pruning

While solving an alpha beta pruning algorithm, how does a heuristic function help to prune as many nodes as possible? If in the worst case, no nodes got pruned, how to prune them using heuristic function?

Comment: Do you mean the evaluation function that you use at the leaves of the tree, or are you asking what you can do if you have an additional heuristic function? (eg an upper or lower bound on the value that you will get when you reach a leaf.)

Comment: Yes, if we were given a function h() which will give the estimate for utility value of each node, how it will be useful to prune as many nodes as possible? Assuming we were given a graph where no nodes got pruned if we solve it normally without using any such function.

Answer (score 0):

In alpha-beta pruning in a perfect-information extensive form two-player game (that is, a game tree) you always have lower and upper bounds during the search from alpha-beta pruning. These bounds essentially say that only values between these bounds are interesting -- anything else will be pruned by an ancestor in the tree.

If you have a heuristic which is a guaranteed lower/upper bound on the value of all children of a given state, you can test that against the bounds for the current state. If the heuristic says the value of all future states are guaranteed to be larger or equal to the upper bound (or smaller or equal to the lower bound), then you can immediately prune and stop your search.

For example, suppose the max player is at a state with `alpha=-10` and `beta = 3`, and your heuristic says the `h(s) >= 5`. Then, you can immediately update `alpha` to `5`. Since `alpha >= beta`, you can prune and return immediately. With the same alpha/beta values at a min node you'd need your heuristic to say that `h(s) <= -10` to be able to prune.

Alpha-beta pruning can reduce a tree size `b^d` to `b^(d/2)`. With a perfect heuristic you could essentially reduce the tree size to d. That is, your heuristic could immediately cut off all remaining children at every state. In practice you won't be able to do so well. But, heuristic can significantly reduce the size of search on top of alpha-beta pruning.